# matches data and calls objects to it if the data matches

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, loops

I want to create a view where it displays 6 data even though there are only 2 data. So the first thing I do is make a data reference like this:

```
var ref_years = [
    {"20181":20181},
    {"20182":20182},
    {"20191":20191},
    {"20192":20192},
    {"20201":20201},
    {"20202":20202}
  ];
```

**and the data to be matched is** :

```
data_match = {
"20181": {
    "jum": 2
},
"20191": {
    "jum": 2
}
}
```

here I aim to create data where for example the year 20181 ref_years matches the 20181 data in data_match it will call and display the number in data_match -> jum.

and if not it displays 0

what I want to show as an example of the following image:
[image]

why do I have to match the data first with ref_years. This is so that the data displayed remains in accordance with the location and position each year in the table :

**this the full code what i try :**

```js
var ref_years = [
        {"20181":20181},
        {"20182":20182},
        {"20191":20191},
        {"20192":20192},
        {"20201":20201},
        {"20202":20202}
      ];
var data_match ={
"20181": {"jum": 2},
"20191": {"jum": 2}
}

let display = [];
let no = 0;
if(data_match != undefined){
  for(var key1 in ref_years){
  let i_key = Object.keys(ref_years[key1]);
    for(var key2 in data_match){
      let i2_key = Object.keys(data_match);
      console.log("**********************");
      console.log("KEYNO1 ===", i_key[no])
      console.log("KEYNO2 ===", i2_key[no])
      console.log("##########################");
        if(i_key[0] === i2_key[no]){
          display.push(<td style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{data_match[i2_key[no]].jum}</td>);
          break;
        }else if(i_key[0] !== i2_key[no]){
          display.push(<td style={{textAlign:'center'}}>0</td>);
        }
      }
      no++;
  }
}
```

I know maybe I can use data calling as below:

```
<td style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{ data_match[20181] ? data_match[20181].jum : '0'}</td>
              <td style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{ data_match[20182] ? data_match[20182].jum : '0'}</td>
              <td style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{ data_match[20191] ? data_match[20191].jum : '0'}</td>
              <td style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{ data_match[20192] ? data_match[20192].jum : '0'}</td>
              <td style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{ data_match[20201] ? data_match[20201].jum : '0'}</td>
              <td style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{ data_match[20202] ? data_match[20202].jum : '0'}</td>
```

but using the method above is not dynamic because the data ref_years and data_match can change at any time. that's why I use the for () function to make it more dynamic.

How do I still display data even though the data is not there with 0 and if there is, it displays the number data_match -> jum. in each ref_years column.

is there another way to display data as I explained earlier? thanks for your attention, sir. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use the following approach. By which you iterate and display the value.

```
const ref_years = [
  { "20181": 20181 },
  { "20182": 20182 },
  { "20191": 20191 },
  { "20192": 20192 },
  { "20201": 20201 },
  { "20202": 20202 }
];

const data_match = {
  "20181": {
    "jum": 5
  },
  "20191": {
    "jum": 1
  }
}

const dataMatchList = ref_years.map((year) => Object.keys(year)[0]);

const dataToDisplay = dataMatchList.map((data) => {

  const hasKey = data_match[data];
  if (hasKey) {
    return {
      [data]: hasKey.jum
    }
  } else {
    return {
      [data]: 0
    }
  }
})

console.log('dataToDisplay', dataToDisplay)

OUTPUT: 
"dataToDisplay",  [{
  "20181": 5
}, {
  "20182": 0
}, {
  "20191": 1
}, {
  "20192": 0
}, {
  "20201": 0
}, {
  "20202": 0
}]
```